# Every polyhedral graph is planar - proof

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Every graph theory book or internet resource on graph theory says **the graph of a convex polyhedron is planar**, i.e. it can be drawn on a plane without edges crossing.

Graph of a convex polyhedron is constructed by drawing vertices of the polyhedron and connecting the pairs that are connected by an edge in the polyhedron. Unfortunately I can't find a formal proof of this theorem. There are some vague explanations based on intuition, Schlegel's diagram, but there's no true, complete, formal proof, or at least I didn't come across one. A proof that makes it obvious, guarantees and makes the reader confident that there is no single special case where the theorem doesn't hold.

If you can at least point a book title or any other resource where a proper proof is given, please do. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is (a weaker version of) one direction of the famed Steinitz' theorem. I know  theorem is covered in Ziegler's $Lectures\ on\ Polytopes$, perhaps you could find a satisfactory proof there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know for sure what would qualify as a formal proof.

How about: Embed the graph in a sphere (since the polyhedron is convex, choose a sphere whose center is inside the polyhedron; and then radially project vertex points and edge points so that they lie on the sphere); then orient the sphere so that the north pole is not a vertex or on an edge of the embedded graph; and then stereographically project the sphere, along with the embedded graph, onto the horizontal plane through the south pole.

Comment: Your answer relies on good imagination skills of the reader, which can be deceptive. That's what worrying me the most - in other branches of mathematics we can operare on symbols in a rigorous manner, while here, in this example, the correctness of the theorem is largely based on intuition.

Comment: @user216094 I disagree. The answer is not a proof, but a sketch; yet, you _can_ transform it into proper proof, where the intuition will still be helpful, but not necessary.

Comment: Ok, that's why I asked for a proper proof, or a resource where it could be found.

Comment: @user216094 This is the standard (outline of) proof  for this question. Intuition and visualization really helps in geometric graph theory, topology, discrete geometry etc. By the way Welcome to MSE.

Comment: @user216094: That's fine.  As I said introductorily, I wasn't sure what would be considered a formal proof.  I'd be happy to see another attempt.

Comment: How do we know that no two vertices of a polyhedron will "land" on a sphere in the same point after radial projection? If they would, is it a problem anyway?

Comment: @user216094: Two vertices won't project to the same point because the polyhedron is convex.

Comment: Could you tell (prove) Why? The explanation of why this is true would make the proof more formal.

Comment: @user216094: Hint: A line that includes a point on the interior of a convex polyhedron will intersect the surface (boundary) of the polyhedron exactly twice. But if the same radial ray hits the surface twice (which is what you'd need for a vertex collision), the opposite radial ray would have to hit the surface at least once (to exit the polyhedron).  Then that radial line (both directions) would hit the surface three times.

Comment: Thanks. What guarantees that stereographical projection from sphere to the plane preserves the structure of the graph, its planarity? I guess it's related to topology, but I don't know much about it (homeomorphism of plane and a sphere with a removed point I guess). Anyway, our goal is making sure the points that are close to each other on a sphere with one point removed are close on a plane as well.

Comment: See here for more info about stereographic projection:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection