# Is the tetrahedron is the unique polytope having the property that all its vertices are adjacent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis, affine-geometry, polytopes

$\textbf{Definition 1:}$ A polytope $P \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is the convex hull of a finite points $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e, $P=\text{conv}(\{x_1,...,x_k\})$. The dimension of P is the dimension of the affine subespace generated by the points $x_1,...,x_k$.

Consider a tetrahedron $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Obviously $T$ is a polytope.
It is easy to show that each pair of vertices of $T$ are conected by an edge .

Now suppose that P is a polytope of dimension $3$ having the property that each pair of its vertices is connected by an edge. Is P a tetrahedron?

Intuitively I think it's true but I can't  rigorously prove that.

By absurd suppose that $P$ is not a tetrahedron, it means that $P$ has at least $5$ vertices ($x_1,...,x_m, m\geq 5$) affinely independet. So there exist hiperplanes $H_{ij}=\{x\in R^n: c_{ij}^Tx = \alpha_{ij} \}$, with $c_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $c_{ij}\neq 0$, $i < j$  ($i,j=1,2,...,m$ ), such that their intersection with $P$ are edges of $P$, and $P$ is in one side of the semiespaces divided by the hiperplanes:

\begin{equation} 
 c_{ij}^Tx \leq \alpha_{ij}, \ \ \ \ \forall x \in P, \ \forall i<j, \ i,j=1,...,m \tag{1}.
\end{equation}

The idea is to use $(1)$ with $x=x_i$, so we get $m$ inequalities for each edge, this is $3\cdot 2^{m-3}m\geq 60$ inequalities. I have a progress of this idea but I'm not be able to get a contradiction and I think there is a simple way to prove that $P$ is a tetrahedron.

Could anyone please help me?

(I am using Ziegler's [Lectures on Polytopes](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-8431-1))

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cs%C3%A1sz%C3%A1r_polyhedron

Comment: @JBL Note that this question is specifically about **convex** polyhedra (see definition 1).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why should I note this?  The Wikipedia article has lots of information that will undoubtedly be of interest to anyone inclined to pose this question.

Comment: (Specifically, anyone who reads it at all closely will notice a formula that relates the number of vertices and the genus of a polyhedron whose skeleton is complete; that formula is sufficient to answer the question posed.)

Comment: A polytope is, combinatorially, a planar graph. A polytope with all vertices adjacent is a complete planar graph. The complete graph on five vertices (and, a fortiori, the complete graph on $n$ vertices for any $n\ge5$) is not planar. QED.

Comment: When you quote the book, please use `>`

Comment: @GerryMyerson to be explicit for the sake of posterity, a *three dimensional* polytope is combinatorially a planar graph.

Comment: @William, yes, good point.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Digit, done, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We assume $P$ is a polytope of dimension three in ${\bf R}^3$, with $n$ vertices. The vertices and edges of $P$ form a planar graph, which let's call $G$. If all the vertices of $P$ are connected, then all the vertices of $G$ are connected, so $G$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices, denoted $K_n$. It's well-known that $K_n$ is planar for $n\le4$, but for all $n\ge5$, it's nonplanar. Therefore, for all the vertices of $P$ to be connected, we must have $n\le4$.

The transition between convex polyhedron and planar graph is well-presented at [Every polyhedral graph is planar - proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151902/every-polyhedral-graph-is-planar-proof)

Comment: I think the mapping to a planar graph could use more explanation. For example, projections from any interior map give a non-intersecting graph on $S^2$, which admits the same graphs as the plane.